# QToolButton - Text on top of icon

Tags: qt, pyside

been searching the forums quite a bit..but couldnt find something reasonable. 
I have a QToolButton and an icon. I dont want to bake the text into the icon image, I d rather have a text using btn.setText("Text").
The problem the text is set right underneath the icon which I dont want in my case. 
It should be on top of the icon. Is there any way to do that? 
I guess with a custom QToolButton..could someone help me out there?

```
btn = QtGui.QToolButton()
btn.setText("Text")
icon = QtGui.QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(os.path.join('path_to_icon.png', QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.On)
btn.setIcon(icon)
```

ideally:

```
icon.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextOnTopIcon)
```

Is there a way to offset the text using style sheet?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: any reason youre not just using a QPushButton?

Comment: Because of the menu functionality and icon state modes

Comment: Delayed popup, menu indicator

Answer (score 0):

Found a good working solution!

```
b = QtGui.QToolButton()
l = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(b)

b.setFixedSize(50, 50)
b.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(50,50))
standardFont = QtGui.QFont("Arial", 10, QtGui.QFont.Bold)
standardFont.setCapitalization(QtGui.QFont.AllUppercase)

text = QtGui.QLabel("Text")

b.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(os.path.join(ICON_DIR, 'csLighting_ftrackTime.png')))
l.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
l.addStretch()
l.addWidget(text, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
text.setFont(standardFont)
b.show()
```